# Variable scope in onclick attribute with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, prototype

I'm using `Prototype` and trying to dynamically access a variable in a loop.

Code speaks better than me:

```js
for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
  $('parent' + i).insert(
    '<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="$('parent' + i).remove()" />',
    {position: 'after'}
  );
}
```

The problem is that `i is not defined` when I click on any of the `Cancel` buttons.

How do I change the variable scope so that `i` keeps the proper value for each button?

I'm not interested in any work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were putting `i` into the quoted string instead of `parent` so it was at the wrong level of scope (conceptually speaking).

```
for (var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    $('parent' + i).insert(
      '<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="$(\'parent' + i +
         '\').remove()" />', {position: 'after'});
}
```

Comment: Don't we have to add a ' while doing $('parent1') for Prototype? He'll have to escape it using \'.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this -

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    $('parent' + i).insert('<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="$(\'parent' + i + '\').remove()" />', {position: 'after'});
}
```

It will be rendered like this -

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="$('parent1').remove()" />
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="$('parent2').remove()" />
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="$('parent3').remove()" />
...
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need that i variable. if you want to remove parent of that input, do:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)" />
```

or if you really really want, you can:

```
for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    $('parent' + i).insert('<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="$(\'parent' + i + '\').remove()" />', {position: 'after'});
}
```